# Stylesheet does not work in Kohana

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I tried several ways to apply the .css and .js files to the view php file. (1) The first way is as shown below:

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<?php echo html::meta('viewport', 'width=980'); ?>

<title>A-TRACK Tutoring</title>
<?php echo html::link('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700',
'stylesheet','text/css', FALSE);?>

<?php echo html::link('media/css/atrack.css',
'stylesheet','text/css', FALSE, 'all');?>
</head> 
......
</html>
```

(2) The second way is as shown below:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980" />

<title>A-TRACK Tutoring</title>
<?php
    if(isset($css)){
    foreach($css as $type => $file){
?>
<link type='text/css' href='<?php echo $file ?>' rel='stylesheet' />
<?php
    }}
?>
......
</head>
```

and in the index action of the controller

```
public function action_index()
{
        $view = View::factory('singleanswer/index');
        $view->css = array(
            'normal' => 'media/css/atrack.css',
            'normal' => 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700',
    ); 
        // Render the view
        $this->response->body($view);

}
} // End Welcome
```

Neither of them works. Does anyone know the reason ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example 2, you are writing over the atrack.css value by using the same key twice in the array.

Change your controller like this:

```
public function action_index()
{
        $view = View::factory('singleanswer/index', array("css" => array(
            Url::site("media/css/atrack.css"),
            'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700',
        ));
        // Render the view
        $this->response->body($view);

}
```

And update your view to this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980" />

<title>A-TRACK Tutoring</title>
<?php
    if(isset($css))
    {
        foreach($css as $file){
                echo "<link type='text/css' href='{$file}' rel='stylesheet' />";
        }
    }
?>
......
</head>
```